ruamel.yaml parser error when using Pyflink over Docker
I'm trying to run a flink job that consumes and provides data from/to a kafka source.In order to submit the job, I'm using the pyflink library.
I'm using:
Python 3.8.0
Flink 1.19.0
The docker file for this project:
version: "3.0"

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    networks:
      - uwb_streaming_net

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    expose:
      - '29092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
    networks:
      - uwb_streaming_net

  jobmanager:
    image: pyflink:latest
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    expose:
      - "6123"
    command:  jobmanager # cp opt/flink/conf/config.yaml opt/flink && jobmanager
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
    volumes:
      - ./opt/flink:/flink
      - ./kafka_test:/kafka_test
    networks:
      - uwb_streaming_net

  taskmanager:
    image: pyflink:latest
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    expose:
      - "6121"
      - "6122"
    command: taskmanager
    links:
      - "jobmanager:jobmanager"
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
    networks:
      - uwb_streaming_net

  app:
    # /flink/bin/flink run -py /taskscripts/app.py --jobmanager jobmanager:8081 --target local
    image: flink-app
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./App.DockerFile
    depends_on:
      - broker
    entrypoint:
      - tail
    command:
      - -f
      - /dev/null
    volumes:
      - ./opt/flink:/opt/flink
      - ./kafka_test:/kafka_test
    networks:
      - uwb_streaming_net

networks:
  uwb_streaming_net:
    external: false
    name: uwb_streaming_net

For the flink job and task manager, I had to use a custom Image over the flink official image. This image adds python to these containers
FROM flink:latest

# install python3: it has updated Python to 3.9 in Debian 11 and so install Python 3.7 from source
# it currently only supports Python 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8 in PyFlink officially.

RUN apt-get update -y && \
apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev && \
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tgz && \
tar -xvf Python-3.8.0.tgz && \
cd Python-3.8.0 && \
./configure --without-tests --enable-shared && \
make -j6 && \
make install && \
ldconfig /usr/local/lib && \
cd .. && rm -f Python-3.8.0.tgz && rm -rf Python-3.8.0 && \
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python && \
apt-get clean && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install PyFlink

# COPY apache-flink*.tar.gz /
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6e/08/b36307d608aa76f14bfc972a0b1ff15920cdee54414864c9dca4cff5d065/apache-flink-libraries-1.19.0.tar.gz && \
pip3 install apache-flink-libraries*.tar.gz && \
rm -rf apache-flink-libraries*.tar.gz

RUN wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4f/d7/633fefca40de6522bb704e9daaabecff27c15c521cede6a0450cedba8b9a/apache-flink-1.19.0.tar.gz && \
pip3 install apache-flink*.tar.gz && \
rm -rf apache-flink*.tar.gz

The python to submit the job fails at the tbl_env.execute_sql(src_ddl) command for any value assigned to the src_ddl variable:
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.table import StreamTableEnvironment, EnvironmentSettings
import os
from pyflink.java_gateway import get_gateway


def main():

  jvm = get_gateway().jvm
  jars_key = jvm.org.apache.flink.configuration.PipelineOptions.JARS.key()
  classpaths_key = jvm.org.apache.flink.configuration.PipelineOptions.CLASSPATHS.key()

  # Initialize the StreamExecutionEnvironment
  env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
  env.add_jars("file:///opt/flink/flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11-1.13.0.jar")

  settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance()\
                                .in_streaming_mode()\
                                .build()

  # create table environment
  tbl_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(stream_execution_environment=env, environment_settings=settings)
  
  src_ddl = """
  CREATE TABLE incomming (
    msg VARCHAR,
  ) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = 'test',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'broker:29092,localhost:9092',
    'properties.group.id' = 'mygroup',
    'format'= 'json'
  );
  """
  tbl_env.execute_sql(src_ddl)
  
  tbl=tbl_env.from_path('incomming')
  tbl.print_schema()
  
  sql = """
  SELECT
    msg,
  FROM incomming;
  """
  
  message = tbl_env.sql_query(sql)
  message.print_schema()
  
  snk_ddl = """
  CREATE TABLE outcome (
    msg VARCHAR,
  ) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = 'test_from_kafka',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'broker:29092,localhost:9092',
    'properties.group.id' = 'mygroup',
    'format'= 'json'
  );
  """
  
  tbl_env.execute_sql(snk_ddl)
  
  message.execute_insert('outcome').wait()
  
  # Execute the job
  env.execute("Kafka Streaming Job")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Thats what I get at the exception log:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kafka_test/flink.py", line 76, in <module>
    main()
  File "kafka_test/flink.py", line 42, in main
    tbl_env.execute_sql(src_ddl)
  File "/flink/opt/python/pyflink.zip/pyflink/table/table_environment.py", line 836, in execute_sql
  File "/flink/opt/python/pyflink.zip/pyflink/table/table_environment.py", line 1613, in _before_execute
  File "/flink/opt/python/pyflink.zip/pyflink/table/table_environment.py", line 1548, in _add_jars_to_j_env_config
  File "/flink/opt/python/pyflink.zip/pyflink/common/configuration.py", line 83, in parse_jars_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 451, in load
    return constructor.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 112, in get_single_data
    node = self.composer.get_single_node()
  File "_ruamel_yaml.pyx", line 707, in ruamel.yaml.clib._ruamel_yaml.CParser.get_single_node
  File "_ruamel_yaml.pyx", line 904, in ruamel.yaml.clib._ruamel_yaml.CParser._parse_next_event
ruamel.yaml.parser.ParserError: did not find expected <document start>
  in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 44
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramAbortException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Python process exits with code: 1
        at org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver.main(PythonDriver.java:134)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:108)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:1026)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:247)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1270)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$mainInternal$10(CliFrontend.java:1367)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.mainInternal(CliFrontend.java:1367)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1335)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Python process exits with code: 1
        at org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver.main(PythonDriver.java:124)
        ... 14 more

The examples provided by Apache works fine, but none of them uses the execute_sql() command
I've tryied to update ruamel.yaml, test different values for the src_ddl. Don't know what else to try.

It is worth to mention that I have tried multiple kafka_sql_connectors without success

What you call the docker file doesn't look like a Dockerfile as docker would use, more like a compose.yaml file that drives docker-compose.
The YAML you pasted here loads without a problem:
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

input = Path('compose.yaml')

for t in ['rt', 'safe']:
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
    data = yaml.load(input)
    # yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
    print('keys:', list(data.keys()))

which gives:
keys: ['version', 'services', 'networks']
keys: ['version', 'services', 'networks']

Your toolchain looks to be using typ='safe'), which is somewhat more restricted than the default typ='rt'), but as you can try both should work.
I suggest trying the actual YAML files that you use with the above program, maybe there is some indentation error, or they have been made on Windows and contain hidden characters that confuse the parser.
